# What is the "Applicable country" field on the Icelandair check-in form?

Tags: visas, usa, check-in, icelandair

As I entered my US Visa information in my booking with Icelandair, there is a field asking for "Applicable Country". I'm Indonesian but received my US visa from Germany, so do I enter Indonesia or Germany in this field?

[image]

Comment: It's not really clear to me what they mean, but since they already ask for the Place of issue, I think they mean the country the visa is for (the United States, in this case), though the fact that the whole section seams to be about US Visas in the first place is quite confusing.

Comment: Is this the full form? Is there anything below Applicable Country?

Comment: @MJeffryes nothing, just like that

Comment: @IhsanHaikal It's very puzzling. I would suggest phoning Icelandair to ask what they want in this field. If you do this, please post an answer to your question to help other people in the future.

Comment: @MJeffryes finally I got the answer from Icelandair after direct chat. They said I should put USA as the section is about USA visa

Answer (score 32, accepted):

After chatting with Icelandair representative, applicable country in this field means that to which country you have the visa to, in this case is USA, therefore I should put USA.

Comment: Man, that is one horrible UX

Comment: I think it's more applicable (pun intended) in visas like Schengen visa, where the issuing county and the country you're visiting (that which visa will apply) can be different. Still, pretty ambiguous.

Comment: It is under the section of adding a visa, so the word applicable is applicable to 'visa' so it makes sense that it is the country the visa is for.

Comment: @さりげない告白Except that it's not a _generic_ visa page: it's already saying "...Visa … issued by a U.S. Embassy or Consulate", so the only possible response would be USA, unless US dependencies (e.g., Guam) would be treated separately.

Comment: If that's the answer (I'm actually criticising the website here not you) then it doesn't make sense at all because it says to fill it only if you have a US visa...wouldn't the only ever option for this field be US?